# How do I know if Memcached is being used as my Rails.cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am trying to implement caching on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine on DigitalOcean and I'm unsure if I setup this correctly. I am in Rails console and I see this:

```
[2] pry(#<DigitizationsController>)> Rails.cache.write("hi", 1)
Cache write: hi
=> 288230376151711744
[3] pry(#<DigitizationsController>)> Rails.cache.read("hi")
Cache read: hi
=> 1
[4] pry(#<DigitizationsController>)> Rails.cache.class
=> ActiveSupport::Cache::DalliStore
```

That seems fine?

But in my actual code, database queries still seem to occur. My code:

```
@search_tag_suggestions = Rails.cache.fetch('digitizations_index', expires_in: 1.hour) do
      [Submission.tag_counts.where('taggings_count > 5').limit(5).order('RAND()')
    end
```

and my terminal output which seems to be fetching from the cache, but why do queries fire afterwards then?

```
Rails.cache.read('digitizations_index')
Cache read: digitizations_index
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  tags.*, taggings.tags_count AS count FROM `tags` JOIN (SELECT taggings.tag_id, COUNT(taggings.tag_id) AS tags_count FROM `taggings` INNER JOIN submissions ON submissions.id = taggings.taggable_id WHERE (taggings.taggable_type = 'Submission' AND taggings.context = 'tags') AND (taggings.taggable_id IN (NULL)) GROUP BY taggings.tag_id HAVING COUNT(taggings.tag_id) > 0) AS taggings ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id WHERE (taggings_count > 5)  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

Why are the database queries firing if it's hitting the cache? Is it because I'm only caching the query plan and it fires when I actually call the variable or when I call the query plan in console which calls `to_s` on it?

My environment has this line:

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

In development, I also see this error. Anyone know why? My guess is that in development I'm not eager loading?

```
 Rails.cache.read('digitizations_index')
 Cache read: digitizations_index
 Unexpected exception during Dalli request: NameError: uninitialized constant ActsAsTaggableOn::Taggable::Collection
```

Comment: My guess as to why it's still firiing a query even though memcached is working is that I'm only caching the query plan which is lazily evaluated once I call the variable.